# create numberd variables in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I created some pseudocode and I'm wanting to convert it into python code I am unsure if it was something I did.  It's possible... I have tried a few things and and looked up some solutions but I couldn't get it to work.

I'm trying to make variables `num1` `num2` `num3` without making my code extra long and having a limit on how many loops I could do (in other similar programs)

Here is my code:
(thanks in advance)

```
START
FOR n = in range 1 to 5
    num(n) = int(input)
    n += 1
num(1) = Largest
FOR x in range 1 to 4
    IF Num (x+1) > Largest 
        Largest = Num(x+1)
    x += 1
OUTPUT (Largest)
END
```

Comment: This sounds you want a `list` – a topic that is well described in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: `num(1) = Largest` <-- should that be reversed so that you define / assign `Largest`? Otherwise your pseudocode operates on an undefined variable

Comment: so i need to put `Largest = 0` at the start?